# I can't get past the js div hiding problem

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I want to hide the divi when I click the button and open it when I click it again. But I couldn't run the normally working code, what could be the reason?

The js code works when there is only one div, but it does not work due to this code I wrote, but I can't solve the problem.

Razor Page

```
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.quest.Count; i++)
                    { 
        <div class="row mt-12" >
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="questcb" asp-for="@Model.quest[i].check">
                    <span>@(i + 1) Soru</span>
                </div>

   

                 <div class="col-md-9">
                        <textarea class="form-control" asp-for=@Model.quest[i].Question rows="3" id="question" hidden></textarea>
                        <label>@Model.quest[i].Question</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mt-12">
                    <div class="col-md-1" hidden>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="A" onclick="clickFunc(this.id)">A</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1" >
                        A)
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-11"  hidden="hidden">
                        <input type="text" asp-for=@Model.quest[i].Answer1 class="form-control" placeholder="" id="answer"
                       aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-11" id="Amod_@i" style="display:inline-block">
                        @Model.quest[i].Answer1
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="mod_@i" onclick="question(this.id)">Cevapları Görüntüle</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
}
```

js code

```
 let question = button => {
                    let element = document.getElementById(`A${button}`);
                    let buttonDOM = document.getElementById(`${button}`)
                    let hidden = element.getAttribute("hidden");
            
                    if (hidden) {
                        element.removeAttribute("hidden");
                        buttonDOM.innerText = "Cevapları Gizle";
                    } 
                    else {
                        element.setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");
                        buttonDOM.innerText = "Cevapları Görüntüle";
                    }
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: Is "hidden" a real attribute for a div? Or does it have to be within a style attribute?

Comment: I didn't want to give the button id and div id the same for different actions.

Comment: CSS `display` property overrides the HTML `hidden` property. `.btn` sets `display: inline-block`. Don't use `hidden` in this situation. Instead use Bootstrap's `.d-none` style class.

Comment: i tried that too, still didn't work                                                                                           `  function question(ID) {
            var selectedID = document.querySelector(`#A${ID}`);
            if (selectedID.style.display == "none") {
                selectedID.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                selectedID.style.display = "none";
            }
        }`

Comment: Since it is an if else structure, shouldn't it work in every way on the first click?

Comment: I renewed the code, the js code works when there is only one div, but it does not work due to this code I wrote, but I can't solve the problem

Comment: Since you are using For Next, why don't u loop the div together and reference it with the [i] and then put a function on the button that refer to the i like HideDiv(@i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the id of div is unique in your code,your js should work.If it still doesn't work,you can try to find the div with the position of the button:

```
 let question = button => {
            let element = $("#" + button).parent().siblings(".col-md-11")[1];
            let buttonDOM = document.getElementById(`${button}`);
            if (element.hidden) {
                element.removeAttribute("hidden");
                buttonDOM.innerText = "Cevapları Gizle";
            }
            else {
                element.setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");
                buttonDOM.innerText = "Cevapları Görüntüle";
            }
        }
```

result:

[image]